# How to set object as selected value of ion-option

Tags: ionic3

I'm using Ionic3 and I can't set selected value if I use the object when showing the page.

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>City</ion-label>
    <ion-select (ionChange)="setDistrictValues(user.sCity)" [(ngModel)]="user.sCity" formControlName="cities">
        <ion-option [value]="sCity" *ngFor="let sCity of city">{{sCity.name}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

I do not know what I miss. if i run `console` in `ionViewWillLoad()`, then `user.scity` already has the correct value,

[image]

but not selected in `ion-option`

[image]

how can I show selected option but enable to edit?

Comment: I suggest you use either template form or reactive form not both..

Comment: Would you give an example of how to use template form?. I've tried without using formcontrol, but it still does not work..

Comment: with just ngModel.. remove formControlName